# Trying to add style tag using javascript (innerHTML in IE8)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, innerhtml

This doesn't work in IE8. I think it's the innerHTML that causes the problem. How to solve?

```
// jQuery plugin
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.someThing = function( options ) {  

        var d = document,
            someThingStyles = d.createElement('style');

        someThingStyles.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        someThingStyles.innerHTML = " \
        .some_class {overflow:hidden} \
        .some_class > div {width:100%;height:100%;} \
        ";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(someThingStyles);

        });

    };

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Who uses style and jquery that way? use classes and\or `.css`

Comment: Why do you use pure JS with jQuery? jQuery was *made* to get around cross-browser issues like this.

Comment: you are missing `var` and `;` `var d = document;
            var someThingStyles = d.createElement('style');`

Comment: @gdoron: It can be very useful to dynamically generate style rules. Also, you can define multiple variable with one `var` statement, which the OP is already doing.

Comment: That script isn't valid. try it with jsList.

Comment: @gdoron - What? Javascript lets you assign a list of vars via `var` and `,` so `var x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;` is a totally valid declaration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### jQuery

Since you're already using jQuery, use:

```
 $('<style type="text/css">' + 
   '.some_class {overflow:hidden}' +
    '.some_class > div {width:100%;height:100%;}' +
    '</style>').appendTo('head');
```

### Pure JavaScript

If you don't want to use jQuery, you have to first append the `<style>` element, then use the `style.styleSheet.cssText` property (IE-only!!).

```
var d = document,
    someThingStyles = d.createElement('style');
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(someThingStyles);
someThingStyles.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');

someThingStyles.styleSheet.cssText = " \
.some_class {overflow:hidden} \
.some_class > div {width:100%;height:100%;} \
";
```

Comment: You could use `document.head.appendChild` and `style.type = ...` instead of this long code

Comment: @vsync `document.head` is only supported since IE9 (and Firefox 4; back then when the answer was written, there were still lots of FF 3.6 users). Setting the type is optional (in HTML5, it defaults to `text/css`). If you don't need to worry about compatibility with old IE, then you can just use `var style = document.createElement('style');style.textContent = '... style sheet here ...';document.head.appendChild(style);`

Comment: Just for anyone paying attention: appending first before setting cssText DOES matter! Odd ball cases that it is needed, but it is important.

Answer (score 9):

If you **weren't** using jquery, IE before version 9 writes to a style element by assigning a css string to the styleelement.styleSheet.cssText.

Other browsers (including IE9+) let you append text nodes to the element directly.

```
function addStyleElement(css){
  var elem=document.createElement('style');
  if(elem.styleSheet && !elem.sheet)elem.styleSheet.cssText=css;
  else elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(elem); 
}
```

Comment: One caveat I ran into: elem.styleSheet is null for me in IE8 until I add the element to the DOM, so I had to move setting the contents of the <style> tag to the end of the code, after document...appendChild.

Comment: This works only if you explicitly add `.setAttribute('type', 'text/css')'` before check for `elem.styleSheet`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the CSSOM (CSS Object Model) spec - http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/

You will probably be interested in the `cssText` property of `CSSRule` objects - http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#dom-cssrule-csstext